# Missing Assembly/Directive Reference for SFML.NET

Tags: c#, sfml

I have been using SFML with C++ for three months now, and recently decided to transition over to C#. I referenced the dlls in my project, added the CSFML dlls to my project, and added the using statements to the top of my code. However, I am given the error posted below after the line:

```
shape.setFillColor(fillColor);
```

What is my problem?

> Error: error CS1061: 'SFML.Graphics.CircleShape' does not contain a definition for 'setFillColor' and no extension method 'setFillColor' accepting a first argument of type 'SFML.Graphics.CircleShape' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code: http://pastie.org/private/eujxnxorisb4ajtp22ovng

Comment: If it's a port that includes C# idioms then `x.setFillColor(...)` could be `x.FillColor = ...` What does intellisense say?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into code SFML.NET code, `CircleShape` inherits from `Shape` which has this method wrapped into property:

```
// SFML.Graphics.Shape
public Color FillColor
{
    get
    {
        return Shape.sfShape_getFillColor(base.CPointer);
    }
    set
    {
         Shape.sfShape_setFillColor(base.CPointer, value);
    }
}
```

so you can simply call:

```
shape.FillColor = ...
```

Comment: After changing the code to say shape.FillColor(fillColor); there was the error CS1955: Non-invocable member SFML.Graphics.Shape.FillColor' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: It is a property, shape.FillColor = fillColor;